# Can not upload APK to google play

Tags: java, android

im trying to upload new application to google play. Already i did this many times so I know process of building/signing with key/uploading and updating apps. Im trying to upload apk and its saying that:
***upload valid package of application***. Apk was builed and signed with created key.

Thanks for responds.

Comment: please share the package name, if its exist on play store and you are updating that??

Comment: package name 'com.comein.kebabiznaweb'. No im not trying to update its new application and im trying to upload first version of app

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.comein.kebabiznaweb please check this package already exist in your country or not

Comment: not exist saying that : 
Sorry, the requested web address was not found on this server.

Comment: Can you please attach the screenshot what message on Developer console it is showing

Comment: https://ibb.co/r3NhHmZ  in translate: Upload a valid application package

Comment: do your applicationId in gradle and package name in android manifest same??

Comment: yes,  applicationId "com.comein.kebabiznaweb" in build.gradle and in manifest  package="com.comein.kebabiznaweb"

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/?hl=en#topic=3450769 please contact to google support, that will definitely help you. Try to live chat, if possible

Comment: okay from august.2021 u need to upload .aab file for new app not .apk

Comment: Great!! Nice to go live now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build .aab, not APK, google announced we have to publish Android App Bundle on Google Play from 01 Aug 2021, for reference I have attached the link below.

> **Important:** From August 2021, new apps are required to publish with the Android App Bundle on Google Play.

[image]

**Reference Link** : https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle