# Can´t roll out new Android version to google play after adding watch support

Tags: android, google-play, wear-os

So whenever I try to release a new version to google play I get the error message
"This version cannot be launched as it does not allow any existing users to upgrade to the new AAB archives".

I´m 100% sure that both the versionName and versionCode have been incremented

Comment: what is your specific question?

Comment: How to fix that error. After some researching it seems like you have to upload two separate apps, one for the phone and one for the watch. Is this something you are familiar with?

Comment: no, I'm not familiar with it ... i commented because i read your post and it does not ask a clear question ... it still does not .. questions do not belong in comments ... this site is not a chat forum ... please edit your post

Comment: Try this it will work, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69074263/can-not-upload-apk-to-google-play/69077580#69077580